# Clear variable to release memory (GPU or CPU) in Lua / Torch

Tags: lua, torch

I am using Lua/Torch to do deep learning tasks. Sometimes I have a very large model to load, which causes memory cost very high, for example:

```
net = torch.load('./path/to/the/model.t7') 
// after this line, the GPU memory cost raises to 2800MB of 3064MB
```

In this case, what if I would like to clear up the variable, just like in Matlab by command `clear var;`?

Answer (score 4):

you can just assign your variable a nil value like this:

`net = nil;`

For garbage collection you can also run:

`collectgarbage();`

Additionally all variables that you declare with local prefix get destroyed once the block of code where they were defined is finished.

Comment: Thumbs up for *always* making variables local (except maybe for those few cases...)